# liquibase data generate ChangeLog with extra spaces

Tags: liquibase

I am migrating data from mssql to oracle.Now I generated the changeLog for mssql by specifying the diff type data.I got the following

```
 <insert tableName="TEST_TABLE">
        <column name="test_column" value="TEST_value                              "/>

  </insert>
```

But Test_value contains too many spaces which I don’t have in my mssql database.It has generated extra spaces.Could any one please help me out this why I got extra spaces

Comment: What is the exact data type definition of that column?

Comment: The datatype is Varchar(max)

Comment: I'm only able to replicate the issue if the actual column value has trailing spaces in it. With just inserting 'TEST_value' I get no extra spaces.  How was the data originally inserted?